# xml parsing to php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have just started learning xml parsing.
My xml file looks like -

```
<company>
    <employee>
        <name>Employee <emphasis emph='em01'>John <emphasis emph='em01'>is great</emphasis></emphasis>.</name>
        <age>25</age>
        <dept>Computer</dept>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Jessica</name>
        <age>25</age>
        <dept>Human Resource</dept>
    </employee>
</company>
```

I want to display this in browser.
I'm able to write code for basic parsing but this tag inside tag seems complicated. Please help.
I want the output as -

> Employee John is great.
>   25
>   Computer
>   Jessica
>   25
>   Human Resource

[My basic php code looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ6PQ.png)

Request help.
Thanks.

Comment: Add the code to the question, not as an image.

Comment: You might also want to tell us what the actual issue is. What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Not able to add the code, it is getting omitted.

Comment: The code in image gives error because its incomplete. I'm able to display the output if the emphasis tags aren't there. Otherwise not able to understand how to display this output as in second employee tag the emphasis tags are not there.

Comment: `strip_tags($employee->name->asXml())` - https://eval.in/779841

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The XML you provided is invalid :

```
<employee>
        <name>Employee <emphasis emph='em01'>John <emphasis emph='em01'>is great<emphasis></emphasis>.</name>
        <age>25</age>
        <dept>Computer</dept>
</employee>
```

Here you have two  opened :

```
<emphasis emph='em01'>John <emphasis emph='em01'>
```

And a third one here :

```
<emphasis></emphasis>.</name>
```

But you close only one and then you close name. You probably just misssed a slash.

Here's a working snippet resulting in your desired format :

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string("
<company>
    <employee>
        <name>Employee</name>
        <emphasis>John is great</emphasis>
        <age>25</age>
        <dept>Computer</dept>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Jessica</name>
        <emphasis></emphasis>
        <age>25</age>
        <dept>Human Resource</dept>
    </employee>
</company>
");

foreach ($xml->employee as $employee){
echo $employee->name . ' <em>' . $employee->emphasis . '</em>';
echo '<br>';
echo $employee->age;
echo '<br>';
echo $employee->dept;
echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Yes. Edited now. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer with a working snippet resulting in the format mentioned in your original post. I made it simple.

Comment: thanks.. but the second <employee> tag doesn't have <emphasis> tags.. and the XML is autogenerated and cannot be edited.